# Content-Disposition header missing at client

Tags: php, http, wireshark

I have a php add which calls LaTeX then passes the PDF to the browser. Since my users will be paying for this service, I want to make sure they are given the option to save the PDF rather than hitting my server again and again.

```
exec("cd tex && latex {$_SESSION['sen_id']}.tex && pdflatex {$_SESSION['sen_id']}.tex", $output);
$pdf = substr($file,0,-3).'pdf';
if (file_exists($pdf)) {
  //header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
  //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($pdf));
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.date('Ymd-His').'-'.basename($pdf));
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  ob_clean();
  flush();
  readfile($pdf);
  exit;
} else {
  echo '<h1>No PDF Produced</h1>';
  echo nl2br(print_r($output,true));
}
```

Using Wireshark, I have noticed that the Content-Disposition header is either not set or doesn't reach the client.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Date: Tue, 22 Jun 2010 14:15:10 GMT\r\n
Server: Apache/2.0.55 (Ubuntu) mod_jk/1.2.14 mod_python/3.1.4 Python/2.4.3 PHP/5.1.2 mod_ssl/2.0.55 OpenSSL/0.9.8a mod_perl/2.0.2 Perl/v5.8.7\r\n
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.2\r\n
Set-Cookie: SESS0d6c65b0599f5b70f6bbc50cfc5b2f94=2b23ba1f74f5f1f641365e9fbb45870d; expires=Thu, 15 Jul 2010 17:48:30 GMT; path=/; domain=.<domain removed>\r\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n
Expires: 0\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
Pragma: no-cache\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n
\r\n
```

So far, the tips I've found say "use octet-steam", "don't use octet-stream", "put spaces after the colons", "Capitalise each word" and "wrap the filename in quotes". I guess there's a lot of misinformation put out by people who got lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the header's being stripped, but [this page](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/) describes how you can encode the file name in the content disposition header and its implications for browser interoperability.

In these cases, I settled for the solution I wrote in the PHP manual page [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/rar.examples.php) (see the first example).

In [your case](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/#attwithasciifilenamenq), you're using an invalid header, which, however, should work with all the major browsers.